# If statement syntax and logic issue

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to switch our surf web cameras off at civilian twilight but having some difficulties with the if statement at the bottom of this code. I am pretty sure it's a syntax issue but can't see it.

```
//Sunrise
//Set Zenneth to 96 which is Civilian Twilight start. Normally set to 90 for "normal" sunrise
$sunrise = date_sunrise(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.575363, -4.037476, 96, 0);
$sunrise = (integer) str_replace(":", "", $sunrise);
// echo "Sunrise: ".$sunrise."</br>";

//Sunset
//Set Zenneth to 96 which is Civilian Twilight start. Normally set to 90 for "normal" sunrise
$sunset = date_sunset(time(), SUNFUNCS_RET_STRING, 51.575363, -4.037476, 96, 0);
$sunset = (integer) str_replace(":", "", $sunset);
// echo "Sunset: ".$sunset."</br>";


// get the current date using a 24 digit hour without leading zeros, as an int

$current_time = (Integer) date('Gi');

if ((($current_time >= 0000 && $current_time <= $sunrise) && ($current_time >= $sunset
&& $current_time <= 2359)) && ($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/langland-webcam" 
| $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/caswell-webcam" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ==
"/webcams/llangennith-webcam" || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/swansea-webcam"))
{
   // Cameras are offline

   return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes. That is one huge `if` statement. I've broken it up a bit:

```
if (
    (
           ($current_time >= 0000 && $current_time <= $sunrise)
        && ($current_time >= $sunset && $current_time <= 2359)
    //  ^^ Should be `||`
    ) && (
           $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/langland-webcam"
        |  $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/caswell-webcam"
    //  ^ Should be `||`
        || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/llangennith-webcam"
        || $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] == "/webcams/swansea-webcam"
    )
) {
```

As commented, first thing I notice: You should be using `||` on the first comparison. Additionally, you later use a single pipe `|` instead of a `||`.

Overall, I would recommend that you refactor this code a bit. Perhaps move the allowed URIs into an array, then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check it. Cumbersome `if`s like this can cause problems--as you just discovered. Something like this:

```
$validUris = array("/webcams/langland-webcam", "/webcams/caswell-webcam", "/webcams/llangennith-webcam", "/webcams/swansea-webcam");
if (in_array($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], $validUris)) {
    if (($current_time >= 0000 && $current_time <= $sunrise) || ($current_time >= $sunset && $current_time <= 2359)) {
        // Cameras
        return true;
    }
}
```